# java collection backed up by multiple collections

Tags: java, collections

I have two collections: `coll1` and `coll2`. I need a collection `coll` which is the union of the two, but I don't want to allocate a new collection. I simply what `coll` to represent a view of the two collection, and to forward calls to them.

Is there a library which offer this?

Comment: I don't know of any libraries, but it does not seem too hard to implement yourself. Declare yourself a class that implements `Collection`, declare the two member collections, and then write the wrapper methods to call the inner methods.

Comment: What kind of collection are we talking about? If you want a `Set`, I'm not sure how you'd implement `size()` without explicitly constructing the union. `List` would be doable, though. You could probably even make it mutable. Although the `toArray` implementation would have to copy the underlying collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps Guava's `Iterables.concat` would meet your needs?

[https://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)](https://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable%29)